# Start Activity from Service and bind them

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm trying to start a new Activity with my Service and have that Activity listening to the SErvice and updates accordingly. It feels like it should be a simple task but I can't figure out a clean way to do it. This is the code I use to start the Activity from the Service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LocalService.this,WebViewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

From there, how would I bind the WebViewActivity to my LocalService. I'm not sure if Binding in the right word, but as described above, I want my Activity to listen to the Service and update accordingly.